# How to get whitesource scan report in Azure Devops pipeline result?

Tags: azure-devops

We are using Whitesource scan in one of the pipelines. We are using the unified agent to generate the report but the report is created in whitesource (saas) website.

Under pipeline result page there is a tab for Whitesource as shown in the screenshot below

[image]

But the report does not get published under this tab. Is there a way to see Whitesource scan report under this tab?

Answer (score 0):

Simply install the https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=whitesource.whiteSource-bolt-v2 Azure extension.  This is the free one for Azure-based pipelines; search "WhiteSource" in the extension marketplace for a paid version with advanced features or a version that supports on-site Azure DevOps Server (FKA TFS).

It looks like you may have already installed one of those.  But...

Once you do that, it's simply a matter of inserting a WhiteSource task into the pipeline, a la:

```
- task: WhiteSource@21
  inputs:
    projectName: 'AZDO_721-onwindows'
```

See https://whitesource.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/WD/pages/1058766849/Azure+DevOps+Services+Integration#Adding-a-WhiteSource-Build-Task-to-Your-Pipeline for more help (on the Azure version).